# How to get key from $form_state in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to grab all of the keys for a particular form submission with the Drupal Form API. The user has the ability to set multiple fields, so I am unsure precisely what those fields will be called and I want to loop through all of the keys.

I know that you can get the value of a field after submission by using this syntax:

```
$value = $form_state['values']['field_name_in_form'];
```

But that doesn't get me the key.

The only information I can seem to find only gives a relatively small list of options, none of which provide me with the key:

https://drupal.org/node/1850410

How should I get this data?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can get the field names by merely calling $form_state['values'] and iterating over this data. Though there's no way specifically to get only the keys of the fields, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys get by referencing the options array in the form definition:

```
$key = $form_state['values']['yourfield'];
$value = $form['yourfield']['#options'][$key];
```

Is this what you mean?